# implementing a looping job executor in java using input

Tags: java, executor

I have a list of values coming in from the input. The list of values can be either from a file opr a ResultSet object or from any other object.

The goal is to execute the next steps in the workflow to run asynchronously basing on the input values.

How can i implement this. Is there any framework i can use here

Here is the code i create to iterate through list of values

```
package com.myframework.loopexecutor.ExecuteLoop;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class LoopExecutor {

    static String dbName;
    static String dbServerName;
    static String lDbName;
    static String lServerName;
    static String serverName;
    static String dbServerNameSecondary;
    static String hive_db = "csp";

    private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(
                "select distinct db_name as db_name,db_server_name as db_server_name,lower(db_name) as l_db_name,lower(db_server_name) as l_server_name,regexp_replace(lower(db_server_name), '-', '_') as server_name,db_server_name_secondary as db_server_name_secondary from csp.curated_input");

        while (res.next()) {
            dbName = res.getString("db_name");
            dbServerName = res.getString("db_server_name");
            lDbName = res.getString("l_db_name");
            lServerName = res.getString("l_server_name");
            serverName = res.getString("server_name");
            dbServerNameSecondary = res.getString("db_server_name_secondary");

            String drop = "Drop table if exists " + hive_db + "." + "IB_C3_" + dbName + "_" + dbServerName;
            String insert = "insert into table " + hive_db + "." + "IB_export_log select " + "\'ib_c3_" + dbName + "_"
                    + serverName + "\' from " + hive_db + "." + "dual limit 1";

            System.out.println("##########################DROP##################################");
            System.out.println(drop);

            System.out.println("############################INSERT##################################");
            System.out.println(insert);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of doing this. If you want to use a framework like Spring then there is an annotation `@Async` you can put on a method to make it asynchronous.

In plain Java you can use `ExecutorService`:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Future<?> future = es.submit(() -> yourCode());
```

Or really quick in Java 8:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> yourCode());
```

There are many options to configure your thread pools etc. and levels of abstractions you can use. It really depends on what exactly it is you want to do. In general, I'd go with something simple, high level first.